# Gnu R: Rename variable in loop

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, rename, crosstab

I would like to create a loop in order to create 15 crosstables with one data.frame (var1), which consist of 15 variables, and another variable (var2), see data which can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109495328/example.csv).

**The code is now able to give results, but I would like to know how I can rename the variable "mytable" so that I get mytable1, mytable2, etc.**

Code:

```
library(vcd) # for Cramer's V

var1 <- read.csv("~/example.csv", dec=",")
var2 <- sample(1:43)
i <- 1
while(i <= ncol(var1)) {
  mytable[[i]] <- table(var2,var1[,i])
  assocstats(mytable[[i]])
  print(mytable[[i]])
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: The answer is: don't do that. Use a list for your output instead.

Comment: Can you, please, be more specific how to do that? I am new to R.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, using names like mytable1, mytable2, etc. for a list of objects is actively discouraged when using R. Collecting all in a `list` is more useful and cleaner.

One way to do what you want would be this:

```
library(vcd) # for Cramer's V
data(mtcars)
var1 <- mtcars[ , c(2, 8:11)]  ##OP's CSV no longer available
var2 <- sample(1:5, 32, TRUE)
mytable <- myassoc <- list()  ##store output in a list
##a `for` loop looks simpler than `while`
for(i in 1:ncol(var1)){
    mytable[[i]] <- table(var2, var1[ , i])
    myassoc[[i]] <- assocstats(mytable[[i]])
}
```

So now to access "mytable2" and "myassoc2" you would simply do:

```
> mytable[[2]]

var2 0 1
   1 4 2
   2 6 6
   3 1 1
   4 2 3
   5 5 2
> myassoc[[2]]
                    X^2 df P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio 1.7079  4  0.78928
Pearson          1.6786  4  0.79460

Phi-Coefficient   : NA 
Contingency Coeff.: 0.223 
Cramer's V        : 0.229
```